# CSS3 Animating position

Tags: html, animation, css

Consider CSS3 animation with ship moving above blue div. For some reason the ship isn't moving. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sea">
    <img src="ship.png" alt="ship" width="128" height="128"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to make CSS3 animation I use the following:

```css
#wrapper { position:relative;top:50px;width:700px;height:320px;
          margin:0 auto;background:white;border-radius:10px;}
#sea { position:relative;background:#2875DE;width:700px;height:170px;
       border-radius:10px;top:190px; }
#sea img { 
  position:relative;left:480px;top:-20px;
  animation:myship 10s;
  -moz-animation:myship 10s; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation:myship 10s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  @keyframes myship {
    from {left: 480px;} 
    to{left:20px;} 
   }
   @-moz-keyframes myship {
     from {left: 480px;} 
     to {left:20px;} 
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes myship {
     from {left: 480px;} 
     to{left:20px;} 
   }
}
```

The ship image isn't moving. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it's an old post but wanted to share this... http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to declare your keyframe outside the css selector, as well as animate an absolutely positioned element.

http://jsfiddle.net/aNvSf/

your modified css looks like this:

```css
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    width:700px;
    height:320px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#sea{
    position:relative;
    background:#2875DE;
    width:700px;
    height:170px;
    border-radius:10px;
    top:190px;
}
#sea img{
    position:absolute;
    left:480px;
    top:-20px;
    animation:myship 10s;
    -moz-animation:myship 10s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:myship 10s; /* Safari and Chrome */               
}

@keyframes myship{
    from {left: 480px;} 
    to{left:20px;} 
}
@-moz-keyframes myship{
    from {left: 480px;} 
    to{left:20px;} 
}
@-webkit-keyframes myship{
    from {left: 480px;} 
    to{left:20px;} 
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

To animate with `left`, `top`, `bottom` or `right`, you either have to have a absolutely positioned or floated element. SO, Change the position to `absolute`.

Also, there was as unclosed braces `}` before you started to declare the keyframes.

```css
#sea img { 
    position:absolute;
    /* ... */
}
```

Braces Error:

```css
    #sea img{
         position:absolute; /* absolute */
         left:480px;top:-20px;
         animation:myship 10s;
        -moz-animation:myship 10s; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-animation:myship 10s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    } 
 /* ^ You have to close the braces here, before declaring the keyframes.
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3CBB/)

Comment: @George, Were you trying to animate the container or img inside?